# Weakly dense C*-algebra in a commutative von Neumann algebra and order convergence

Tags: operator-theory, c-star-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space and $\mathscr{A}$ a commutative norm-closed unital $*$-subalgebra of $\mathcal{B}(H)$. Let $\mathscr{M}$ be the weak operator closure of $\mathscr{A}$.

**Question**: For given a projection $P\in\mathscr{M}$, is the following true? $$P=\inf\left\{A\in\mathscr{A}:P\leq A\leq 1\right\}$$

It seems that the infimum must exist and is a projection, but I am not able to show that the resulting projection cannot be strictly bigger than $P$. Also, if the above is true, what happens if $\mathscr{A}$ is non-commutative?

Comment: By $P=\inf U$ do you mean $P\leq A$ for all $A\in U$ and if $Q\leq A$ for all $A\in U$ then $Q\leq P$?

Comment: @SmileyCraft Yes, and if we assume $U$ is norm-bounded, then $\inf U$ is the same as $\lim U$ when we regard $U$ as a decreasing net, in the weak operator topology.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I found a counterexample.

Take $\mathscr{M}=L^{\infty}[0,1]$ and $\mathscr{A}=C[0,1]$.

Let $\mathbb{Q}\cap[0,1]=\left\{r_{n}\right\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ be an enumeration of rationals in $[0,1]$, and define $$E:=\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(r_{n}-\frac{\epsilon}{2^{n}},r_{n}+\frac{\epsilon}{2^{n}}\right)\cap[0,1]$$ for some small $\epsilon>0$ so that $m(E)$ is strictly less than $1$. Clearly, the only continuous function $f:[0,1]\rightarrow[0,1]$ satisfying $\mathbb{1}_{E}\leq f\leq 1$ is $f\equiv1$, but the projection $\mathbb{1}_{E}$ is not equal to $1$.

Comment: Yes, that gives you a counterexample. You might struggle a bit if you want to make it concrete, it's not obvious to me how to choose $\epsilon$, and the order of the enumeration probably makes a difference. It might be easier working with a the complement of a fat cantor set.

Comment: Maybe I overlook something, but the only projections in $\mathscr A$ are $0$ and $1$. If you take $P = \chi_{[0,1/2]}$, then $P$ is not the infimum of as described in the question, since the infimum is $1$.

Comment: @AndréS. If $P$ is the indicator of $[0,1/2]$, then the set described in the question is the set of all continuous functions $f:[0,1]\rightarrow[0,1]$ such that $f(x)=1$ for all $x\in[0,1/2]$. So in this case, $P$ is indeed the infimum of that set. The fact that there is no nontrivial projections in $\mathscr{A}$ does not matter here.

Comment: Ah okay, I had projections in $\mathscr A$ in mind. So is the pointwise infimum of those continuous functions that majorize the indicator, call it $P$, then the infimum in the sense of operators on $L^2([0,1])$ ?

Comment: @AndréS. Yes, and the pointwise infimum as functions on $[0,1]$ is equal to the infimum in the sense of operators in this case, because the pointwise infimum can be obtained by a countable sequence of approximations.